# UIImage/UITabBarItem not loading images properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to load an image into a `UITabBarItem` and have that be viewed in the `UITabBarController` that is my `window.rootViewController`. You can see exactly what I"m doing in my code. I have three sets of images; I don't care where they are located, but I would like to be able to access at least one of the sets!

I'd like `one`, `two`, and `three` to be the images that I'm loading. I have tried a number of options and combinations, but none of them seem to work. The present makes it load a blank (all black?) image which I assume means it's having trouble reading the file, but found it (as opposed to what I've had before, which is completely blank).

Please find in the following images:

1. My code (at present)
2. The structure of my project
3. The resulting output

By the way, the images that it should be loading are graphical representations of the numbers "1", "2", and "3". They are most certainly not black/gray/blue rectangles.

I hope this is clear! Thank you!

[image: Picture of window for clarity!]
[image: The output, for clarity!]

Answer (score 0):

From the document:

> On a device running iOS 4 or later, the behavior is identical if the
>   device’s screen has a scale of 1.0. If the screen has a scale of 2.0,
>   this method first searches for an image file with the same filename
>   with an @2x suffix appended to it. For example, if the file’s name is
>   button, it first searches for button@2x. If it finds a 2x, it loads
>   that image and sets the scale property of the returned UIImage object
>   to 2.0. Otherwise, it loads the unmodified filename and sets the scale
>   property to 1.0. See iOS App Programming Guide for more information on
>   supporting images with different scale factors.
>
> On iOS 4 and later, if the file is in PNG format, it is not necessary to specify the .PNG filename extension. Prior to iOS 4, you
>   must specify the filename extension.

You can set a breakpoint at  `UIImage *one =` line, and to see the value of image one, two, three, step by step. if value is nil, check the image name if correct, if not, try following code:

```
NSArray *items = @[[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"First" image:one tag:1],
                   [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Two" image:two tag:2]
                   [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Three" image:three tag:3]];
self.tbc.tabBar.items = items;
```

Comment: The UIImages are not nil, and it still gives me gray rectangles.

Comment: maybe the type of image, can you just use png image, and have a try?